# Error running app on iOS

Tags: nativescript

I'm on MacOS platform now and did a full install of the tools for {N}.

I can build my app. I see it being installed on the emulator and can also see the splash screen and then crash.

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Project successfully built
Successfully deployed on device with identifier '7E5B1A70-9579-4510-8279-E43522B8537C'.
1   0x107ee05dc -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
2   0x107a0f4e2 main
Jan 16 15:09:50 macs-iMac test4[2821]: 3   0x10d72a68d start
4   0x1
[native code]: JS ERROR NSErrorWrapper: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Jan 16 15:09:50 macs-iMac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.7E5B1A70-9579-4510-8279-E43522B8537C.launchd_sim[2436] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.test4[0x3494][2821]): Service exited due to Segmentation fault: 11
```

Any help???

The app runs fine on Android.

I also download the groceries app on macOS and it builds and runs ok - just wanted to make sure the tools were installed properly.

I see the culprit is `JS ERROR NSErrorWrapper: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

How can I find out what that could be???

```
{
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "readme": "NativeScript Application",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.test4",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.4.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-calendar": "^1.2.0",
    "nativescript-email": "^1.3.4",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^2.4.1",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.2.3",
    "nativescript-purchase": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^0.2.5",
    "nativescript-themes": "^1.1.0",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.19.0",
    "babel-types": "6.19.0",
    "babylon": "6.14.1",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "^0.4.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: I commented out my app.ts file - so nothing in my code is running. I still get the same message.

Comment: The package.json might help here

Comment: @Brad I've attached the package.json file to my original post. I also created a dummy blank project and added one plugin at a time. That works. The only difference I could find are some revision differences from what I have in my actual project compared to the dummy project. I did notice there were a lot of extra folders in my node_modules folder - babel, lazy related. I assume that's only for Android.

Comment: Everything in the package.json looks okay. I was wanting to make sure you weren't running @next (nightly) versions of runtimes and core-modules. Without testing the project, if you have a good IDE you should be able to search the entire project for `NSErrorWrapper` and see if it's being used in any of the plugins. I doubt it and iOS isn't my best friend :) so I'm not much help other than trial and error for figuring out iOS issues. As you noted the different versions in the dummy vs. your project is a clue that something is off with a module you're adding (plugin maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem.

```
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
        <android>
            <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto,*,auto,auto">
                <Label row="0" col="0" text="test"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </android>
        <ios>
        </ios>
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>
```

I hadn't defined something for iOS action-bar - that was causing the segmentation fault.

Yes I was planning to add it once I got to the Mac platform.

A simple error message would have been nice.